# TFS will not allow download of a project

Tags: tfs, download

When I try to download a solution folder from TFS, it reports that the folders are up to date. When I try to get a specific version and tick the two boxes to overwrite existing data I still get the same message. When I delete the entire folder from my local drive I get the same message. I then removed my workspace (the entry for the parent folder) and removed the entire parent folder (containing numerous other solutions). Get latest still gets everything except the solution I am trying to retrieve. Nothing seems to give me the solution I am trying to retrieve. The reason I need to do this to begin with is because one file (Program.cs) dropped off my local drive after I did an undo checkout on it plus some other files. TFS showed an exclamation mark next to the file indicating it was missing. I can see it in Source Control so I tried to get latest of that file from there but it said it was up to date / already downloaded. Any ideas?

Further: Although I can see the files on VSTS, when I try to download them I end up with an empty ZIP file. When I try to view individual files directly in VSTS, I get this error:

> TFS.WebApi.Exception: The items requested either do not exist on the
> server at the specified versions, or you do not have permission to
> access them.

Anyone ever encountered this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the correctly behaviour.

According to TFS permission setting, most groups and **almost all permissions**, **Deny trumps Allow**. If a user belongs to two groups, and one of them has a specific permission set to **Deny**, that user will **not be able** to perform tasks that require that permission even if they belong to a group that has that permission set to **Allow**. More details please refer this MSDN link: [Change access levels](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/connect/change-access-levels)

In your situation, you need to set the denied access to allow or remove your user account in that specifically group. Everything should be OK.

Comment: Saved my day today. Spent one hour trying to figure this out until I stumbled upon this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if you are in a group that has been denied access (eg view access is set to "deny"), then you will not have access even if you're in other groups that have been given access to the project. This must have changed recently, since it only stopped today. Shouldn't permissions work the same way they work everywhere else Microsoft?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for that error is that other users do not have a correct (sufficient) access rights. To solve that problem go to organisations settings and select "Users" from there. The user, who wants access the project, should have the same access level rights as the user who have uploaded the project.